# How can I use MS Graph to list Azure AD instances for a given LiveID account?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

I have a customer who is using a liveID account to manage 20+ different Azure AD directories.

How can I get a list of all the Azure AD instances associated with this account?

I tried using [this graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) to figure out which query was correct, however every time I tried to consent to a Directory Read consent, the tool didn't accept it. (it would run, but the checkbox would be cleared upon inspection )

My goal is to determine at runtime, which instances have had "administrative consent" to access applications stored in my tenant.   Then I will prompt the administrator to consent for those apps.

I'm tagging as MSAL and ADAL, I can't get either to work with a MSFT Account that is an admin for Azure AD

**Testing**

I am using this [MSFT sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web) and posted this debug code in on any controller that is currently using `ActiveDirectoryClient`.  This code works for any AzureAD account.

```
            var pagedCollectionTenants = await client.TenantDetails.ExecuteAsync();
            do
            {
                var tenants = pagedCollectionTenants.CurrentPage.ToList();
                foreach (var tenant in tenants)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tenant.DisplayName + " id " + tenant.ObjectId + " " +
                        tenant.Street + " " +
                        tenant.City + " " +
                        tenant.State + " " +
                        tenant.PostalCode + " " + tenant.PreferredLanguage + " " + tenant.TelephoneNumber);

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("   ** Assigned Plans **");
                    foreach (var plan in tenant.AssignedPlans)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "   "  + plan.AssignedTimestamp + " " + plan.ServicePlanId + " " + plan.Service + " " + plan.CapabilityStatus);
                    }

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("   ** Provisioned Plans **");
                    foreach (var provisionedPlans in tenant.ProvisionedPlans)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("   " + provisionedPlans.CapabilityStatus + " " + provisionedPlans.ProvisioningStatus + " " + provisionedPlans.Service);
                    }

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("   ** Verified Domains **");
                    foreach (var domain in tenant.VerifiedDomains)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("   " + domain.Type + " " + domain.Name + " " + domain.Initial + " " + domain.Id + " " + domain.Capabilities + " " + domain.@default);
                    }
                }
                pagedCollectionTenants = pagedCollectionTenants.GetNextPageAsync().Result;
            } while (pagedCollectionTenants != null);
```

The results for a MSFT Account is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> > How can I get a list of all the Azure AD instances associated with this account?

I am not sure whether Microsoft Graph api expose the api call to get a list of all the Azure AD instances associated with this account . But i noticed in azure new portal , i could choose Multiple Windows Azure Active Directories by clicking my user name on top right part of portal . Use Fiddler you could find api call which portal use to get multiple Windows Azure Active Directories information :

```
https://ms.portal.azure.com/AzureHubs/api/tenants/List
```

Then you could add `Windows Azure Service Management API` in `required permissions` in your app :
[image]

Then using  [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) , you need to get access token for `Windows Azure Service Management API` by setting resource :`https://management.core.windows.net/` .

After you get the access token , you could try below api calls to get all the Azure Active Directories :

```
POST https://ms.portal.azure.com/AzureHubs/api/tenants/List
Authorization: Bearer xxxxx
```

The result :

[image]

If your account is a microsft account and want to authenticate with app , you could add the account as [external user in AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-create-users-external) .

Comment: This is great! Yet it would be really nice to have this in Microsoft Graph.