# Can't retreive displayName for an Azure AD tenant

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

**Issue**

Can't retreive displayName for a tenant

**What is s OK**

My application is a multi-tenant web site. 
I authenticate the customer with Open Id Connect and get an access token (say **armToken**) from a code grant flow in ordre to run this request:

*https://management.azure.com/tenants*

That get a list of all tenants where customer is declared. Say it is **Tenants**.

This works fine.

**Where it goes wrong**

Then I want to get some more information about all tenants as it's display name.
So I need to run this request for each tenant on **Tenants**:

*https://graph.windows.net/[tenantId]/tenantDetails?api-version=1.6*

I use a code like this:

```
foreach (Tenant tenant in Tenants)
{
   string graphToken = await 
   GetAuthorizationToken("https://graph.windows.net/", tenant.TenantId);
   string json = await GetGraphRequest($"https://graph.windows.net/{tenant.TenantId}/tenantDetails? api-version=1.6", graphToken);

// I parse JSON to get my informations
}
```

**What I tried**

The issue is probably in **GetAuthorizationToken** method that don't retreive a proper token.
I tested all **AcquireTokenAsync** signature, none of the is working except:

```
AcquireTokenAsync(string resource, ClientCredential clientCredential);
```

But the token received only works in the case where the tenant tested match TID found in user's claims.

Depending the tenant I get several messages:

*{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}*

==> But I gave all possible permissions on *Microsoft Grant*

or

*{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_IdentityNotFound","message":{"lang":"en","value":"The identity of the calling application could not be established."}}}*

=> effectively I have no claims as OID in the token

- I checked there are not slash issue in the uri.
- I checked the Graph request with Postman to be sure this is not a issue in the code
- I am global admin

**My question**

I really don't know what I can do more.

This should be possible because I can see it working here:

[https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureResourceExplorer/](https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureResourceExplorer)

But it does not use ADAL library. So maybe thre is a limitation about that library?

Answer (score 1):

If user login your application with azure ad account , using azure ad graph api tenantDetails operation , you could only get the tenant details which issues the access token . Otherwise , it will throw error : `Invalid domain name in the request url` .

To get a list of all the Azure AD instances associated with user account , you could try Windows Azure Service Management API , Please refer to [my reply here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43867643/5751404) . In response ,you could get displayName,domainName,ID of the tenants.

Comment: I just get **"AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_"**. Seams doesn't support code grant. That's surprising because its working fine with the portal.

Comment: If you registered web app in azure portal , you need to provide the client secret during code grant , please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) for more details .

Comment: Any update ?  if you have any question ,please feel free to let me know .

Comment: I am sick for a few days and didn't check since your last post, sorry!

Comment: I hope you will soon recover :)